# show group of sets using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am having trouble figuring out how to write this code.
I have 1000 name db entries and I need to echo the results in sets of 4.
So the set # counts per each 4 entries until end of data.
How can I do this with php?

My result should look like this:

```
<div id="set-1">
 <div>Name1</div>
 <div>Name2</div>
 <div>Name3</div>
 <div>Name4</div>
</div>

<div id="set-2">
 <div>Name5</div>
 <div>Name6</div>
 <div>Name7</div>
 <div>Name8</div>
</div>

//and so on......
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's extremely helpful to see your attempt whenever you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your returned vlaues from your DB are in an array. I made a mock array just to mimick an array with 1000 entries.

```
    <?php
        $mockNameArray = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
        {
            $mockNameArray[$i] = "Name" . $i;
        }
    ?>
```

Since you have a set number returned from your DB it is easy to run a for loop instead of a foreach loop. I would do something like this.

```
<?php for ($i = 0, $x = 1; $i < 1000, $x < 251; $i++, $x++): ?>
    <div id="set-<?php echo $x; ?>">
        <div><?php echo $mockNameArray[$i]; $i++; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $mockNameArray[$i]; $i++; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $mockNameArray[$i]; $i++; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $mockNameArray[$i]; ?></div>
    </div>
    <p>
<?php endfor; ?>
```